# Changing content of a fancybox with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I have a link in my menu that opens up a fancybox with some ajax contents. This box contains links, like a menu for the data shown in the fancybox. I would like to be able to click these links and change the content of the fancybox but all I manage is to open a new box instead, which makes the screen fade to white and back which makes it look like it's flickering.

I tried using an array of content dictionaries to just change the  but couldn't get it to load any of them. I've also added a rel to the links making it a album with arrows on the side so I can go to the next/previous and that works fine except that's not the type of navigation I want. It must be possible to do the same through links instead, but I can't figure out how. Can anyone help me with this?

Edit: a small [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PYTQT/1/) of some things that I tried.

Comment: @Joy, don't have much code, but here's some..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fancybox supports iframes. You could make an iframe instead. And put in another html-page there.

Comment: In the end I opened a html-page with ajax in the lightbox. This page contained a menu and an iframe in which I loaded the page using `$('#iframe_id').attr('src', url);`

Answer (score 0):

You can try on each link

The links located on the same server or different domains?

Have you tried with onclick="window.location.replace(url)"

I use fancybox on our web system and that helped me with fancybox

Comment: You will need to open fancybox as an iframe and use the window.location on the links inside the fancybox iframe

Comment: Ah, I didn't know you meant an iframe. That's what I ended up doing anyway, see comment for accepted answer. Thanks anyway.